# Are there proficiencies for Goldsmithing and creating Jewelry?

Tags: crafting, adnd-2e, proficiency

There is the jeweler secondary skill, but that is another set of rules.

Are there any proficiencies for working gold and creating jewelry?

Answer (score 6):

Yes. In the [Land of Fate (Al Qadin)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Land_of_Fate) boxed set, there is a proficiency that fits the bill:

> Metalworking(General) 1slot (Dex / 0)

It allows to create metal objects, like jewelry, lamps, etc. out of gold, brass, copper, silver and other metals.

Answer (score 4):

There are several. There is **Metalworking** from *Al-Quadim* and **Gold Casting** from *Maztica* both in the *General* proficiency group. **Gem Cutting** from the *Player's Handbook* would be useful if you wish to incorporate gems into the jewelry you make and falls into the *Rogue, Priest, Wizard* and *Psionicist* proficiency groups.

Also, jewelry making is often considered an art form. You would have to ask your DM for approval but if they agree then you could select *Jewelry Making* as your art form under the **Artistic Ability** proficiency listed in the *Player's Handbook*. **Artistic Ability** is in the *General* proficiency group.

Comment: What is the slot and check for gold casting?

Comment: @Mindwin refining rough gems is still important if you intend to use them for jewelry. Gold Casting's an Intelligence based proficiency and only requires 1 slot. The check modifier is -1.

Comment: @Mindwin Also, not to nitpick, but i believe the term you meant was lapping, which is a process used by a gem cutter, also called a lapidary or lapidarist. Lapidation, as far as I can tell, means "to pelt with stones" and was used as a capital punishment way back when. Its kinda an important distinction...

Comment: no, no! by all means nitpick. you are 100% right that I got the wrong stoning verb. And by your awesome nitpicking i learned two new verbs today. +∞